# Block all SSID's Except One / No Exclusive BSSID

Tags: wireless

I need to block all ssids except one.  The one that i do want could have over 250 BSSIDs for the same ssid.  There must be another way than the single ap BSSID method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First way is to allow only connection from one router based on mac address using `iptables`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source <mac_address_of_you_router> -j ACCEPT
```

and drop anything from different mac address on input with command

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m mac ! --mac-source <mac_address_of_you_router> -j DROP
```

Or you can use some script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ssid`

```
#! /bin/bash

REQUIRED_CONNECTION_NAME="<name-of-connection>"

activ_con=$(nmcli con status | grep "${REQUIRED_CONNECTION_NAME}")

if [ "${activ_con}" -a ! "${activ_con}" ];
then
    ifdown wlan0
fi
```

Witch mean, if is not connected to `REQUIRED_CONNECTION_NAME` aka home wifi dispecher will do `ifdown wlan0`.

Replace `wlan0` with you wifi interface name

Try, maybe work for you.